# Load the ,trained model save, in pytorch for chatbots

Tags: python, pytorch, chatbot

I ran the code of this tutorial ([link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/chatbot_tutorial.html#run-training)) and after a while learning the model was completed and I chatted with the trained model. After exit the program, in the save directory next to the program file, 8 files with a tar extension were created.
I guess they are trained model saved files, what should I do to load those files and reuse them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "[Run the Model](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/chatbot_tutorial.html#run-model)", they describe what you should do. More specifically, there is this code in their snippet:

```py
# Set checkpoint to load from; set to None if starting from scratch
loadFilename = None
checkpoint_iter = 4000
#loadFilename = os.path.join(save_dir, model_name, corpus_name,
#                            '{}-{}_{}'.format(encoder_n_layers, decoder_n_layers, hidden_size),
#                            '{}_checkpoint.tar'.format(checkpoint_iter))
```

And you basically need to uncomment the `#loadFilename` and set the `checkpoint_iter` to the iteration you want. After that, you can skip the training part, because you already ran it, and run the [evaluation code](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/chatbot_tutorial.html#run-evaluation) again.